# Access request URI in a custom library class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, request, uri

I use a class defined in `lib/myclass.rb` and need to access the request URI in one of its methods. Is there a constant with the URI which can be accessed from my class or I need to define it myself? Where and how can I do the definition (except in controller or view)?

#### UPDATE:

The following method solves the problem via a class variable as suggested by [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530815/access-request-uri-in-a-custom-library-class-in-rails/4531781#4531781)

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :define_uri

  def define_uri
    MyClass.uri request.fullpath
  end
end

# lib/myclass.rb
def MyClass.uri u
  @@uri = u
end
```

### However,

I am still interested in getting the request URI outside of controller. Any ideas how?

Comment: It would help a lot if you included some stripped down sample code showing the class definition, and method stubs showing how you'd like to access the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the URI is initialized/stored in the same class, you'll have to define it yourself.

If the URL is defined when the class is initialized then create either a class or instance variable. All methods will be able to see it.

Instance variable:

```
class Blah
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def method1
    url = @url
  end
end
```

Class variable:

```
class Blah
  @@url = nil
  def initialize(url)
    @@url = url
  end

  def method1
    url = @@url
  end
end
```

If the URL comes from a different class then you'll have to use whatever accessor that class provides. If there isn't one then you could try something like `OtherClass::URL_variable` where you dig up the variable name of the URL by looking in the source or by extending that class to provide an accessor.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick, but "wrong" answer**: Define a before filter in your controller that sticks the the uri in Thread.current... basically setting a thread-safe global variable. You can access Thread.current from anywhere.

This is undesirable, because it couples the class to the request/response cycle and global state. Imagine trying to unit-test this class, and you'll start to see why this is no good. The API to use this class is now "munge this global variable, and then call this method."

**Better answer:** Pass the uri as an argument into the method that needs it, or into the initialization of the class if multiple methods need it.